# VBScript - Creating and then killing a process with a hidden window in?

Tags: windows, ssh, vbscript

I have this simple script helping some of my users SSH over VNC into a non-priveledged account on a server.  I am using Putty and TightVNC, both of which are in the same directory as the script.  It goes like this:

```
Dim sshtunnel
Dim desktop

Set tunnel = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = tunnel.run("putty -ssh user@#.#.#.# -L 9000:localhost:5901 -pw password",0,false)
Set desktop = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = desktop.run("tvnviewer -host=localhost -port=9000",0,true)
'Somehow, end the process created by tunnel.run
```

**Steps:**
1.) Start Putty with appropriate port forwarding invisibly (*works*)
2.) Start the remote desktop (*works*) 
3.) Wait for the remote desktop session to be closed (*works*)
 4.) Close the SSH tunnel (kill putty) (**need help**)
Obviously, I need it to kill Putty - but I can't find any way to communicate with a process started with `tunnel.run` method.  I can't find a way to make processes create with `exec` invisible.  How should I approach this?

Thanks!

PS: I know there is a hardcoded password.  It is more appropriate to remedy that at deployment time in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways. The one that fits in with what you are doing is to run taskkill.

```
Return = tunnel.run("taskkill /im PuTTY.exe /f",0,false)
```

or

```
Return = tunnel.run("wmic process where (Name=""PuTTY.exe"") call terminate",0,false)
```